# INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Inserts Wrong Order

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to insert and update data. Problem is it doesn't insert the way I thought it would.

```
foreach($urls as $key => $value)
    {
        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO urls (url_id,parent_id,url) VALUES ('$key','$parent_id','$value') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE url = '$value'");
    }
```

The table should look like this:

```
url_id   |   parent_id   |   url
1        |   1           |   http://cnn.com
2        |   1           |   http://msn.com
3        |   1           |   http://amazon.com
```

It ends up looking like:

```
url_id   |   parent_id   |   url
1        |   1           |   http://cnn.com
3        |   1           |   http://amazon.com
2        |   1           |   http://msn.com
```

If another row is inserted, it will go above:

```
3        |   1           |   http://amazon.com
```

I understand SQL doesn't have an order, but why does the query insert this way.

Comment: A table in SQL does not define any order, so literally you cannot insert in the "wrong order".

Comment: Ok, but I'm wondering why it inserts that way.

Comment: Well, that is totally implementation dependent. As @AndreKR said, you want to `order by` when you query your data instead ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no inherent order in a MySQL table. Use `ORDER BY url_id` when SELECTing from it.

Comment: Thanks. I know I can use ORDER BY when I select. I've been practicing queries for awhile, but never ran into a query that inserts in this way. It's always a 1,2,3,4 order; never 1,4,3,2. I just want to know if there is a reason for that.

Comment: Have you tried a `TRUNCATE TABLE` (*not* a `DELETE FROM`!)? Usually the first time after that it inserts in linear order until the table file becomes fragmented again.